# How to set config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host = '#''} on per environment basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

Right now I'm using this which works for the development host, but I have to manually change the {:host => ""} code when I move to production.

#### post.rb

```
def share_all
  url =  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(self, :host => 'localhost:3000')
  if user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').any?
    user.twitter_share(url)  
  end
end
```

I'd like to use this and then define the default_url_options per environment:

#### post.rb

```
def share_all
  url =  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(self)
  if user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').any?
    user.twitter_share(url)  
  end
end
```

I've tried adding this to my config/environments/development.rb but I still get the "Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]" error

#### development.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

And I even tried it this way:

#### development.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost", :port => "3000"}
```

EDIT:

I've now also followed this and still the same error guide http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

#### application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include ApplicationHelper
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      { :host => "example.com"}
    else
      {:host => "example1.com"}
    end
  end
end
```

This is driving me crazy, what am I missing here???

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Okay I figured it out the correct way to write it is

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

:)

Comment: If you have dynamic host's then it's not thread safe. I found only one way, is to set Thread.current in ApplicationController through before_filter, and use this host in Model.

Comment: is there a way to set it from config.routes or something like that?

Comment: @juanpastas: I just added it to the top of `routes.rb`: `Example::Application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com'`

Comment: FWIW I think is probably best addressed by using the _path helpers versus the url helpers... i.e. relative path versuse absolute url. :) This is usually a problem with rspec.

Comment: Switching to _path helpers only helps so far. For instance, if you use redirect_to, it calls url_for under the hood so you need to pass :only_path => true each time you call it.

Comment: Where do you do this for rails engine?

Comment: Also, using `_path` helpers is not working scenario if you have an ActiveJob what wants to use url helpers

Comment: In 5.1.4 this does not work in web page rendering, but only work in rails console. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781000/474597 for more details.

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000', protocol: 'https' }` if you want to change to `https` too

Answer (score 13):

### Inherit your Application's `default_url_options` from `ActionMailer`.

You want to keep things as DRY as possible so, ideally, you don't want to hard code your host and port in multiple places for the same environment, unless your `ActionMailer` *actually* uses a different host and port than the rest of your `Application`.

To set the `default_url_options` for your entire `Application`, simply add the following line to your `config/environment.rb` file (changing `MyApp` to your app's name):

```
# Set the default host and port to be the same as Action Mailer.
MyApp::Application.default_url_options = MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

This will fix your problem and automatically set your `Application`'s `default_url_options` to the same as your `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`:

```
$ MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}

$ MyApp::Application.default_url_options
#=> {:host=>"lvh.me", :port=>"3000"}
```

Comment: If you do this, you might want to add a comment above your Action Mailer `default_url_options` stating that the Application `default_url_options` inherit them. Wouldn't want someone changing the Action Mailer `default_url_options` not realizing it will change them for the entire application.

Comment: @DavidGay Agree. Ideally, I would rather set the `default_url_options` explicitly and then specify that `action_mailer.default_url_options` inherit from those. For some reason, I didn't do it like that 2.5 years ago.

Answer (score 7):

You have to restart your server before the changes to this file takes effect.

Comment: I've totally restarted my server like 10 times trying this :) but no worky

Answer (score 6):

**config/environments/development.rb**  (any other environment, same)

add this row with host that you want

```
routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score 5):

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "your host" }

for instance your host localhost:3000

you can put this in test.rb, development.rb, production.rb  files host could be different from environment to environment

Answer (score 4):

This is how I usually go about this problem:

First, properly set your `config/environments/production.rb` (and other environments) from the `rails new` auto-generated file:

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # [...]
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: "https://your_app.your_domain.tld"
  } # You may also use an env variable ENV['HOST'] if necessary
end
```

Then, go back to your `config/application.rb` and set to inherit from this ActionMailer configuration:

```rb
require_relative "boot"
require "rails/all"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module YourModule
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # [...]
    config.after_initialize do |app|
      app.routes.default_url_options = app.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Best answer :D Above solutions did not work for me, the default_url_options was always nil. after_initialize makes it work. Rails 7.1

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this with Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3. The behavior I was seeing was basically that every path I added would fail with `Error during failsafe response: undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`. In production it worked fine, but in my development environment, I would get the error mentioned above.

---

The fix for me was add this to `controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
def default_url_options
  if Rails.env.production?
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: "www.production-domain.com", protocol: 'https' }
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000', protocol: 'http' }
  end
end
```

I was then able to run my development environment on my local.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself trying to generate a URL in a rake task. It's definitely non-obvious and many of these solutions will work. My solution is a take off from @joshua-pinter's but done in the environment file. For example my `development.rb` looks like:

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  …
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = self.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  …
end
```

with the appropriate changes made to `production.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

For me whats worked is

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { host: "yourhosthere"} # e.g. yourhosthere=localhost:3000 or yourhosthere=example.com
```

because if you already set a port in the config files then changing the [:host] only will result in an error

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your specific url options in each environment file with

```rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'hostname', port: 3000 }
```

And then set the default url options in your `config/routes.rb` file with

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
  ...
end
```