# How to get full asset path in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using `gmap4rails` in my application which says to specify a marker you should define a method in your model. But how can i get full image url for that?

Now I have the following code in my model

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
{
  "picture" => helpers.asset_path("marker.png"),
   "width" => 20,
   "height" => 33
}
end

def helpers
  ActionController::Base.helpers
end
```

But this only give me path for an image?

I've also tried to do it like this

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url + helpers.image_path("marker.png")
```

but that gives me an error:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score -2):

Look at [How to set config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host = '#''} on per environment basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691727/how-to-set-config-action-controller-default-url-options-host-on-per).
You need to set Rails.application.routes.default_url_options or to pass :host option to root_url(host: 'foo.bar')
To set different host option for different environments you can use ./config/environments/xx.rb files

Comment: well, it worked for me. I mean:
_config/environments/xx.rb_ with `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` and then
`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url + ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("marker.png")`
`=> "http://localhost:3000//assets/marker.png"`