# Rails: Make Route Helper Methods Available to PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within a Plain Old Ruby Object (PORO) in my rails app: I have the following method:

```
def some_method
  content_tag(:li, link_to("Do something", somewhere_path(object.id)))
end
```

First: the object didn't understand the method `content_tag`, so I added the following which made the object understand that method:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
```

Then the object didn't understand `link_to` so I added the following which made the object understand that method:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

Now, it doesn't understand my route: `somewhere_path(object.id)`.

**Question:** How can I make the PORO in my rails app understand the helpers which generate routes?

**Followup Question**: Is there an easier way to include all of this functionality into my PORO object?  Perhaps there is a way to only `include` one major module and get all of this functionality (as opposed to perhaps needing to require 3 different modules).

Comment: `init`? Or do you mean `initialize`?

Comment: @tadman no I literally ment the the method `init`.  I answered my own question below, so you can see what the class would look like.

Comment: Having `init` and `initialize` is asking for confusion, especially as in other languages `init` is what the initializer method is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either have to do what you describe in your self-answer (link to [revision I refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8f0d8cfe-17e8-4443-b2fb-b7fc1fec90c3/view-source)), or inject some context into your POROs. Where context is something which knows all those methods. Something like this:

```
class ProjectsController
  def update
    project = Project.find(params[:id])
    presenter = Presenters::Project.new(project, context: view_context) # your PORO
    # do something with presenter
  end
end
```

And your PORO would look like this:

```
module Presenters
  class Project
    attr_reader :presentable, :context
    def initialize(presentable, context:)
      @presentable = presentable
      @context = context
    end

    def special_link
      context.somewhere_path(presentable)
    end
  end
end
```

Me, I like neither of them. But sometimes we have to choose a lesser evil.

> If anyone happens to know of a current way to get access to all of these methods with one include statement then let me know.

Why, yes. There is a way.

```
module MyViewCompatibilityPack
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def url_helpers
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end

class MyPoro
  include MyViewCompatibilityPack

  ...
end
```

Comment: see my updated answer.  Let me know if you know of how to do this becuase it appears as though it just isn't possible inside a PORO object.

Comment: I updated my answer yet again. See above.  Also, I believe your answer will not "always" build the paths right via `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.  I ran into issues while using passenger, as it didn't know the domain.

Comment: Yeah, in these situations, you should specify the host explicitly. Or set it [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5725343/125816).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that actionview-related methods are not available to POROs.

In order to get all the great stuff from actionview: you need to utilize the `view_context` keyword.  Then: you can simply call upon actionview-related methods from your `view_context`:

```
class BuildLink
  attr_accessor :blog, :view_context

  def initialize(blog, view_context)
    @blog = blog
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  def some_method
    content_tag(:li, link_to(“Show Blog“, view_context.blog_path(blog)))
  end
end
```

So for example: from your controller you would call upon this PORO like so:

```
BuildLink.new(@blog, view_context).some_method
```

For more information, see below references:

- [Rails doc on view_context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-view_context)
- Utilization of `view_context` via presenter pattern, shown in [this article](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/)
- [Railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) which talks through utilizing `view_context` via presenter pattern

Comment: It's pretty dirty to self-post an answer and not even acknowledge what Sergio did with a simple upvote. He's also right, a presenter is what you're talking about. What you're doing here is highly irregular and not recommended.

Comment: his method has the limitation of not knowing the domain.  Espcially if using passenger, the url will be wrong. Also: prior to updating my answer: I did post a comment to him and he did not respond back. "Dirty" is putting it pretty strong.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding his code. There's a reason this sort of stuff doesn't leak out. If you want that sort of functionality, define helpers. This is exactly what they're for.