# Error 500 appears on production when deploying by heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Help me please. This error appears "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information" when I'm deploying to heroku. But locally it works fine
Also I tried this to do these steps
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQJS0.jpg 
But it didn't help me
The problem is when I'm signing in as new user (It's Rails tutorial). Here is some logs

```
     heroku logs --tail
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590786+00:00 app[web.1]: [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7]      9: <%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590787+00:00 app[web.1]: [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7]     10:                                                     email: @user.email) %>
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590852+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T13:16:01.590783 #4] FATAL -- : [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7]
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590901+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T13:16:01.590857 #4] FATAL -- : [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7] app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb___51652882317290060_70044044082940'
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590903+00:00 app[web.1]: [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7] app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
    2019-01-16T13:16:01.590905+00:00 app[web.1]: [fd635b17-afbe-46dc-96f0-619bbf8f11e7] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
    2019-01-16T13:51:01.604733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2019-01-16T13:51:01.608754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2019-01-16T14:50:38.084642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2019-01-16T14:50:41.934933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2019-01-16T14:50:47.596849+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:25122
    2019-01-16T14:50:47.597604+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
    2019-01-16T14:50:48.311163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.157432+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.157329 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550] Started GET "/" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-16 14:50:50 +0000
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.158279+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.158206 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550] Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.159174+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.159106 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.159706+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.159645 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.160648+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.160585 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.7ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.160837+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.160776 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.161274+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.161209 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.164178+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.161509 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:50.164181+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:50.161753 #4]  INFO -- : [c9b34a35-d1cd-4de0-8d94-dd785bc68550] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.8ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:55.285534+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:55.285435 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30] Started GET "/signup" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-16 14:50:55 +0000
    2019-01-16T14:50:55.286488+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:55.286416 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
    2019-01-16T14:50:55.438699+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:55.438577 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
    2019-01-16T14:50:55.445021+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:55.442522 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.192013+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.191893 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (752.3ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.192199+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.192115 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (753.4ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.192980+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.192900 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.5ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.193154+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.193093 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.193560+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.193498 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.193869+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.193808 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
    2019-01-16T14:50:56.194186+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T14:50:56.194120 #4]  INFO -- : [f148e8a0-1283-47d8-9cfd-13d9dfa45c30] Completed 200 OK in 908ms (Views: 756.3ms | ActiveRecord: 69.5ms)
 C19-01-16T15:05:06.429588 #4]  INFO -- : [ee8dfcc8-f9e6-4b88-b34c-76981b3c818d] Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 20.6ms)
    2019-01-16T15:37:24.694353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.307531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.458187+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.481651+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2019-01-16 15:37:26 +0000 ===
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.482088+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
    2:184:in `run'
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.482808+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.482810+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.482811+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    2019-01-16T15:37:26.482813+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
    2019-01-16T16:08:11.826631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2019-01-16T16:08:19.763046+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
    2019-01-16T16:08:19.763079+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
    2019-01-16T16:08:19.763081+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    2019-01-16T16:08:19.763083+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
    2019-01-16T16:08:25.437415+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5013
    2019-01-16T16:08:25.437840+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
    2019-01-16T16:08:25.845703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2019-01-16T16:08:27.912870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-spire-36002.herokuapp.com request_id=fed2543d-a7b5-448c-acd6-94dd896daa16 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
    2019-01-16T16:08:28.600223+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:28.600079 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
    2019-01-16T16:08:28.605740+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:28.605661 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.480045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/signup" host=calm-spire-36002.herokuapp.com request_id=cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1476ms status=200 bytes=3472 protocol=https
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.465380+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.465241 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (863.6ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.465481+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.465410 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (865.2ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.468773+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.468694 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (1.6ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.469749+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.469673 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.475476+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.475398 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.0ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.476851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.476777 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
    2019-01-16T16:08:29.477240+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:08:29.477173 #4]  INFO -- : [cd923035-45c6-4c11-869f-7a1265130075] Completed 200 OK in 1469ms (Views: 879.1ms | ActiveRecord: 505.5ms)
    2019-01-16T16:09:24.694871+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:24.693260 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] Started POST "/users" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-16 16:09:24 +0000
    2019-01-16T16:09:24.694882+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:24.694541 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
    2019-01-16T16:09:24.694887+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:24.694634 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8H+A3e7TtDvzCvHdRt1wOuXxDGo4UmHnhAFOixiN2AqZ0lKcY4OG+gScKmlRc31nGZIT0bPYIBQckWRIcTWpcw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"aaaa", "email"=>"aaaas@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
    2019-01-16T16:09:24.841768+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-16T16:09:24.841665 #4] DEBUG -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]    (1.1ms)  BEGIN
    2019-01-16T16:09:24.988238+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-16T16:09:24.988127 #4] DEBUG -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]   User Exists (65.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "aaaas@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.170744+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.170598 #4] DEBUG -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]   User Create (22.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "aaaa"], ["email", "aaaas@gmail.com"], ["created_at", "2019-01-16 16:09:24.988622"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-16 16:09:24.988622"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$oy5pyDRqTwem3GGBR.ZdnO4779IYLCFxUyRadgRefLVm3PdtVpeNW"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$nxGhsXHK/q/UOoj5YG50meivBK/kD.aCF7HiRgn1H72X9NzegKokm"]]
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.173673+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.173575 #4] DEBUG -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]    (2.4ms)  COMMIT
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.185053+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.184951 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.187573+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.187499 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (2.4ms)
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.187728+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.187654 #4] DEBUG -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 13.6ms
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.190341+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.190287 #4]  INFO -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 495ms (ActiveRecord: 167.8ms)
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191554+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.191464 #4] FATAL -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191619+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.191560 #4] FATAL -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191856+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.191763 #4] FATAL -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]      6: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191860+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]      7: </p>
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191863+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]      8:
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191865+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]      9: <%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191867+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]     10:                                                     email: @user.email) %>
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.191983+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.191857 #4] FATAL -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51]
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.192053+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T16:09:25.191986 #4] FATAL -- : [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__3781546992025811969_70102224775860'
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.192055+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.192056+00:00 app[web.1]: [06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
    2019-01-16T16:09:25.193461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=calm-spire-36002.herokuapp.com request_id=06a105d0-fbb7-4184-86d4-8cc55010ec51 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=513ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
```

This is the code after running command  heroku logs --tail

And after adding host value I have these errors:

```
heroku logs --tail
2019-01-22T14:46:14.855869+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2019-01-22T14:46:14.855871+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2019-01-22T14:46:15.060779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-22T14:47:28.973034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-22T14:47:32.686902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2019-01-22T14:47:34.858216+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-01-22T14:47:34.858241+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-01-22T14:47:34.858249+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-01-22T14:47:34.858250+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-01-22T14:47:37.287329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154464+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154522+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma)
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154572+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154575+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154577+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154578+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154580+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154582+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154583+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154585+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154587+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154588+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154590+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154592+00:00 app[web.1]: (erb):12:in `<main>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154594+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154596+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154597+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154599+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154600+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154602+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154604+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154605+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154607+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154608+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154610+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154611+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154613+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154615+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154616+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154618+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154620+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154621+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154623+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154624+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154626+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154627+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154629+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154635+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154636+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154638+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154640+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154642+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154644+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154645+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154647+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `depend_on'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154650+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154652+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154653+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154655+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154657+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154658+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154660+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154662+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154663+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154668+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154670+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154672+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154673+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154675+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154676+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154678+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154680+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154682+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154683+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154685+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154686+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154688+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154690+00:00 app[web.1]: config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154691+00:00 app[web.1]: config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154693+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154695+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154696+00:00 app[web.1]: config.ru:in `new'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154698+00:00 app[web.1]: config.ru:in `<main>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154700+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154701+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154703+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154704+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:318:in `load_rackup'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154706+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:243:in `app'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154714+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:145:in `load_and_bind'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154715+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154717+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154719+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154720+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154756+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2019-01-22T14:47:37.154758+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2019-01-22T14:47:38.379593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=6b199937-6426-4e86-bb9d-82eb1f5da202 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-22T14:47:38.967589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=0f9d2333-b8d0-460d-a152-6a3fe019d0c6 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: This is unreadable, would you mind formatting it please ? It will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: Plus add more lines, it looks like the error message is below

Comment: Sorry, already edited it

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states:

```
2019-01-16T14:52:25.691412+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-16T14:52:25.691344 #4] FATAL -- : [4a832d9c-6928-438c-acbc-abb1d09269ba] ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

You're missing a host for your link, so it crashes.
You can add it in you environment files (for heroku, production.rb).

Example on another post:
[How to set config.action_controller.default_url_options = {:host = '#''} on per environment basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691727/how-to-set-config-action-controller-default-url-options-host-on-per)

Comment: I added it. It didn't help :(

Comment: Your second issue doesn't seem related. Please open a new post.